# Symmetric matrix with non negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Can you exhibit a symmetric matrix with all zeros on the main diagonal and with all non negative eigenvalues?

My guess is that the only way to do so is with a matrix where all entries = 0, but I don't know how to formalize it.

May you help me?

Comment: the trace is zero, so the sum of the eigenvalues is zero, but they are all nonnegative. It means that all the eigenvalues are zero, and since the matrix is symmetric it is diagonalizable. It means that the matrix itself is zero

Comment: Thank you, Exodd.
I made quite the same arguments.
The matrix is symmetric so all the eigenvalues are real. The trace is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, that so it's 0. Since if we had a positive eigenvalue we should also have a negative one to bring the sum to 0, then all eigenvalues must be 0.

But now, why it cannot exist a matrix with all 0 eigenvalues different from the one "all zeros"?

Comment: because symmetric implies diagonalizable, so you can write the matrix $S$ as $MDM^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and contains the eigenvalues. Since the eig are zero, $D=0$ and $S=0$

Comment: Perfect, thank you, Exodd, I got it!
Solved!